# How to automatic create override implementations of a base class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to know how could I create the implementation of an abstract method in all the specific classes that inherit from him.

I need it because I have an abstract class, I create one abstract method on it, but there is around 50 specific class to implement this method, and will be so boring implement one by one (even with the `ctrl` + `.` shortcut).

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  We're not just going to give you code.

Comment: @roryap The question is not about code, is about how to automatic implement the override methods of an abstract class. I'm asking for a shortcut of visual studio or something like that.

Comment: No, you will have to implement each one by hand. The IDE cannot know how you want to implement every single override - virtual, abstract, final, new, ...

Comment: @AndersTornblad :/ Sad... Any implementation will be fine to me, just to the compiler doesn't show errors while I'm developing.  Thank you by the answer

Comment: 1-If all the classes implement the same method with the same code, why it's abstract then? 2-If there will be some differences in code create an intermediate class which implements that function and do the rest of classes with the same implementation inherit from it.

Comment: @Gusman Obviously my classes will not have the same code, its the cause that I'm using inherit.  I want to create a default implementation just for now, to the compiler doesn't accuse errors while I'm developing one at a time.

Comment: Then do it virtual instead of abstract and leave it empty or with the default behavior on the abstract class

Comment: If you need this just while developing, simply make the class non-abstract. When you are done, add `abstract` back in and have the compiler see if you broke any rules.

Comment: @Gusman Come on, I was very stupid, obviously it can solve my trouble. HAHAHAHA Let me delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right-click on every class and select **Implement Abstract Class** which will create an empty metmber-body doing nothing but throw an `NotImplementedException`.

However I can´t see any reason why you should do that. If your method should have a default-implementation it should not be `abstract` in base-classd but `virtual`:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
    virtual void DoSomething() 
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}

class Derived : MyBaseClass {
    override void DoSomething() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(); 
    }
}
```

You do not have to implement the method on all derived classes now. So as long as you´re *testing* (or for whatever weird reason you need this) you can stay on your *default implementaion* whereas when *releasing* the software you *force every class to implement* the member by chaning modifier from `virtual` to `abstract` and delete the method-body.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I don't want to use this shortcut, because I have  A LOOOOT of classes and it will be boring :P

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind you did not understood what this answer is saying, that's the correct way to do things, you don't need to override in all the classes that property, only on the ones you want to change it's behavior.

Comment: @Gusman I think the problem is that OP needs different implementations for EVERY type, however just for testing all he wants is any dummy implementation which will be implemented in more detail afterwards.

Comment: @Gusman "You can right-click on EVERY CLASS and select implement abstract class "

Comment: @HimBromBeere if there is a different implementation for each one, then there's nothing to do as each one has a different code... you need to write it

Comment: @HimBromBeere Exactly this.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind You only need to do that if you must replace the default behavior, if you code the default behavior in your class as virtual you will need to override it ONLY on the ones with different code.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It is a nice 'trick' to solve my problem, is not exactly what I wanted, but will solve my problem. After I implement all the classes I change the modifier to `abstract` and everybody will be happy.

Comment: Exactly. The only other possibility is that one you want to avoid.

Comment: Can you have an abstract method with a body?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider No, but if you read carefully I did not write this. I said for testing hOP might use an empty virtual method, whereas on release he can change access-modifier from virtual to abstract whereby OP must implement method on every derived class.

Comment: Upon careful inspection of your answer I found the following: *" when releasing the software you force every class to implement the member by chaning [sic] modifier from virtual to abstract."* I looked carefully, but the post ended there, so that was all you suggested to do when "releasing the software".  I assume that by "changing the modifier from virtual to abstract" you'll produce code which won't compile (but I'm not 100% sure, that's why I asked). You will additionally need to remove the function body, and add a semicolon. I suppose. I'm not sure.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Ah, now I see what you ment, I updated it accordingly, hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can follow the pattern of the [adapters for Java event listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#eventAdapters).

They are an intermediate class sitting above the abstract class (interface in Java), providing a more or less meaningful (actually, empty) default implementation for all abstract functions. Your classes inherit (either just for now, or forever) from this adapter, overriding only some of the functions.

If all your classes inherit from this adapter as a permanent solution it is probably questionable why you had the abstract class to begin with. Defining an interface with no implementation makes sense only in order to avoid the restrictions concerning multiple inheritance in Java and C#. If the base class has some implementations anyway, you can as well provide a default for the remaining abstract methods, too. If that is undesired because in production code inheritors must be forced to implement their own methods, because there is no reasonable default, one could actually disable the implementing code with conditional translation (and, for example, make it dependent on a DEBUG or TEST flag during compilation).